# .envファイルがlsコマンドの実行結果に表示されない

Tags: unix

■疑問
なぜ.envファイルがlsで表示されないのか？

結果的には作業ディレクトリ直下に存在した
`find <dirpath> -name .env`

その後viで中身をいじって正しい挙動の変化を確認したのでファイルは正しく存在していたと思われる

■背景
ターミナル（teraterm）で開発中のプログラムのソースやgitなどを管理していました。
あるタイミングで開発中のwebへのアクセス権に関してエラーが表示され、.envファイルの設定を確認しようとしました。
どこにファイルがあるのか失念していたので、思い当たるディレクトリに移動してlsで探しましたが見つからず。
結果的には曖昧な記憶を頼りにfindで見つけました。

■環境
windows10,Teraterm

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`ls` は 先頭に `.` があるファイルをデフォルトでは表示しません。
このため、 `-a / --all` オプション、または `-A / --almost-all` を指定する必要があります。

```
-a, --all
      do not ignore entries starting with .
```

> `.` から始まる項目を無視しない。

```
-A, --almost-all
      do not list implied . and ..
```

> （ `--all` に加えて）`.` 及び `..` を表示しない。

Comment: タイミング良く、どうしてそうなったかの日本語訳が出てますね。https://mattn.kaoriya.net/etc/20190419120056.htm 太古のUNIXで "." と ".." をスキップするためのコードのバグが由来とのこと。